# I want to create Check in Screen layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create Check in Screen layout in android like this

please help me how can i create layout like this.

[image]

please somebody help me

Comment: That's Apple layout. First read the Android design guidelines: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: You mean the rounded borders ?

Comment: I don't want actionbar and TABs in this layout. I want only rounded borders and textview design like this

Answer (score 2):

First create two shapes, one for Default state of Button, second for pressed state:

### default_shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners 
    android:radius="5dp"/>    
      <gradient 
    android:startColor="#ffd700"        
    android:endColor="#daa520"
    android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

### pressed_shape.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<corners 
    android:radius="5dp"/>    
      <gradient 
    android:startColor="#ffF8dc"        
    android:endColor="#daa520"
    android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

then create a selector:

### your_selector.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_shape"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/default_shape"
      android:state_pressed="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/Default_shape" />
  </selector>
```

and then give the selector to Your button as Background:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/your_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_selector" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

You could Play a Little bit with the Colors from the shape...this is just an example how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Add given file in to drawable folder and make changes for background color. use this as background of your TextView.`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/something"
            android:centerColor="@color/something_else"
            android:startColor="@color/something_else_still"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners
            android:radius="3dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>`

Comment: use same color for android:endColor, android:centerColor and android:startColor

Comment: I want to set text view alingment like this how can i set textview on the right of logo?

Comment: how can I set name label and how can i set name on the right of name label?

Comment: textView.setText(your lable);textView.setBackground(R.drawabl.filename);

Comment: I mean how can i set company logo and compay name in one line?

Comment: an  I want to set Name Lable and Name in one line

Comment: use set left drawable in your lable by XML file OR by java code